# nodejs ssh2 handling data responses in persistent shell

Tags: node.js, ssh

I want to open a persistent connection with the ssh, type commands and handle their responses. Commands will likely hook on to each other, such as changing directories then running another command, so exec does not seem to be an option from what I understand. With php and phpseclib it was simple, I could simply do:

```
$ssh->sftp('cd /some/dir');
$response = $ssh->sftp('ls');
```

However with ssh2 and nodejs there appears to be only one handler for all incoming data, so no matter what I write, it will all come back to the same function, which makes it hard to determine what is what. Especially since I can not control what comes back. If I did an 'ls' I would get a list of files and folders, but if I did a grep or tail I would get a different type of list, but my handler would not know which is which to handle/parse them properly.

How can I solve this issue?

Perhaps I am looking at this the wrong way and just need someone to take the PHP glasses off. My goal is to build a small local app that will connect to my servers through ssh and do complex tasks like grabbing my access logs and parsing all the data into a more readable format for me, or maybe creating a new sites-available config file and then a2ensite'ing it, or vardumping my databases and downloading the files to back them up locally, etc.

Comment: Are you using the same handler for different `exec`s? Include the code of your current attempt.

Comment: they are not execs, I am using the .shell. The execs would create a new connection every for every command from what I understand, which is not what I want.

Comment: You can find a shell example here: https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 . This is the same shell command I use, and it shows that there is only one handler for all responses. So I run a ton of commands with .write and all the responses go to the same stream.on('data') handler.

Comment: You should use multiple `exec` if you want to be able to differentiate between the outputs of different commands because that's the only way you'll get a separate callback for each of them. And no, it wouldn't create new connection, as long as you're doing everything inside the callback of one single `conn.on('ready'`. (callback=handler)

Answer (score 0):

ssh.connection.shell is used to get access to remote shell in interactive manner. For connections to do work & come back, shell is not the right option. 
Read this,
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/210
You can do the same with npm#ssh2,

```
conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
if (err) throw err;
sftp.readdir('foo', function(err, list) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.dir(list);
  conn.end();
});
```

});